# Android 5.0 FDE stopped asking for password during boot

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

The settings still says encrypted, but it no longer asks for passwod during boot. Lockscreen password is still there. How did this happen (bypassing encryption)?

Google search indicated this is not unheard of. Imo this is a serious security issue.

Comment: Are you definitely still on 5.0? The developer preview for Android N adds a feature where it can boot to lockscreen but not need the encryption password until you want to run apps.

Comment: Yes no system update in 2016 so far

Comment: Are you using Greenify or some app that uses accessibility services? [This](https://blog.g3rt.nl/android-lollipop-encryption-user-interface-flaw.html) blog explains the behaviour you reported, if you are

Comment: There is a registered bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79309) related to accessibility

Comment: Indeed it's caused by Lastpass fill helper, but only on 1 device with android 5.0. My other android 5.0 devices did not have this problem.

Comment: Some people claim this can be caused by fingerprint scanner as well.

Comment: On other devices, are there any apps that use accessibility ? If not it points to accessibility using apps on your device to the problem. Can you please check and comfirm

Comment: All use Lastpass fill helper (accessibility), only 1 has this problem.